# Finding natural linewidth's

Tags: experimental-physics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, spectroscopy

I want to check whether my fit parameter for the width of a Lorentzian fit on my digital spectroscopy data for Helium (the 5875 Angstrom line) is what you would expect from the uncertainty principle, but I can't find the mean life for this state anywhere in literature? How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, check [NIST Atomic Spectra database](http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/ASD/lines_form.html) for Helium lines in your wavelength range. You will find your line at 5875 A (not at 5785). The database provides you with the Einstein coefficient $A_{kj}$, which is the inverse of the radiative lifetime of the excited state.

Also, you will find that the line is split to several (hyperfine structure?) components, which will also contribute to the total line width.

Comment: This gives me $\Delta_E = \hbar/\tau \implies \Delta_\lambda = \frac{2\pi c}{A_{ki}}$ = 26.6 meters...? (Where I have used $c =2.998 10^8 $ m/s and $A_{ki}=0.7070$ (from http://physics.nist.gov/PhysRefData/Handbook/Tables/heliumtable3.htm))

Comment: Sorry for late reply. The $A_{ki}$ in your table should be multiplied by $10^8$, see the header of the table.